# Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for MultiselectDropdown: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, multi-select

I was using [angular-2-dropdown-multiselect](https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect) of version `1.0.2`.

**On html**

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="users" [texts]="userDropdownTexts" [settings]="userDropdownSettings" [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers"
                  name="selectedUsers" required></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

**Controller**

import statement

```
import { IMultiSelectOption, IMultiSelectSettings, IMultiSelectTexts } from 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect';
```

Component class

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    userDropdownSettings: IMultiSelectSettings;
    userDropdownTexts: IMultiSelectTexts;

    // object for multi-select drop down
    private users: Array<any> = [];

    selectedUsers: number[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userDropdownSettings = {
            pullRight: false,
            enableSearch: true,
            checkedStyle: 'checkboxes',
            buttonClasses: 'btn btn-default',
            selectionLimit: 0,
            closeOnSelect: false,
            showCheckAll: false,
            showUncheckAll: false,
            dynamicTitleMaxItems: 4,
            maxHeight: '170px',
        };

        this.userDropdownTexts = {
            checkAll: 'Check all',
            uncheckAll: 'Uncheck all',
            checked: 'checked',
            checkedPlural: 'checked',
            searchPlaceholder: 'Search...',
            defaultTitle: 'Select Users',
        };
}
```

Everything was working fine. I updated this library from `1.0.2` to `1.0.3` and now this is showing

```
Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for MultiselectDropdown: (?, ?).
    Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MultiselectDropdown: (?, ?).
        at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1595:29) [<root>]
        at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1793:18) [<root>]
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18458:33) [<root>]
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18333:28) [<root>]
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17973:26) [<root>]
        at CompileMetadataResolver._loadDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17849:25) [<root>]
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18050:56) [<root>]
        at Array.forEach (native) [<root>]
        at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18049:43) [<root>]
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27290:60) [<root>]
        at Array.forEach (native) [<root>]
        at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27289:45) [<root>]
        at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27244:54) [<root>]
        at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27210:23) [<root>]
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/index.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/index.js
        at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1595:29) [<root>]
        at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1793:18) [<root>]
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18458:33) [<root>]
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18333:28) [<root>]
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17973:26) [<root>]
        at CompileMetadataResolver._loadDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17849:25) [<root>]
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18050:56) [<root>]
        at Array.forEach (native) [<root>]
        at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18049:43) [<root>]
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27290:60) [<root>]
        at Array.forEach (native) [<root>]
        at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27289:45) [<root>]
        at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27244:54) [<root>]
        at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27210:23) [<root>]
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/index.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/index.js
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: I think we need to see some code that allows to reproduce.

Comment: Did you add the multiselect module to `imports: [...]` of the module where you're using it?

Comment: yes!!I have added. this was working fine with 1.0.2 version.

Comment: What do you mean with "1.0.2 version" with what version did it start failing?

Comment: with 1.0.3 version

Comment: Sorry, somehow missed that sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the library to version `1.0.4` and now it is working fine. There may be an issue with the library itself.

Here is the closed github issue related to this

https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/issues/102#event-1009144997